# Meaning of long beep

Tags: motherboard, noise

Today I was just minding my business, doing some programming and watching some Twitch stream, when my computer made a loud beep that lasted for about a second. It sounded like one of those beeps you get during boot, but longer.

I have looked around and found that it might get caused by CPU overtemp, but I checked and my CPU cores are between the 56 and 63 degrees C. Also the other temperatures are fine (HDD around 35, SSDs around 30 and GPU around 47 degrees C)

It happened twice before in the past couple of months.

I checked the event viewer immediately and it didn't show any Critical, Error or warning events in the past hour.

I have the following specs:

- Mobo: Asus Z97-P
- CPU: i5 4670k
- RAM: Corsair vengeance 4x4GB DDR3
- Video card: palit gtx 1070
- SSD1: Samsung 840 EVO 250GB
- SSD2: Crucial CT120M500SSD1
- HDD: Seagate ST2000DM001-1CH164
- PSU: Corsair CS650M

What could be the issue?

Edit: I just ran the windows memory diagnostics tool, no problems found.

Comment: A single long beep is rather unusual, especially considering your PC is already running. I'll take a wild guess, can you run something intensive on the GPU and see if the beep may be originating from there? Some GPUs will beep if they aren't getting enough power.

Comment: I have already played games like GTA 5 and Rainbow 6 siege in the past month without beeps, so I dont think that is the issue.

Comment: Beeps from the system speaker when already booted do typically indicate an issue detected by hardware monitoring features, such as the temperature monitors on various components. That said it's possible to send "beep" codes to the system speaker from both windows and Linux consoles, and I can't imagine it would be too hard to program something to do the same. So perhaps it's a bit of software doing it for some reason?

Comment: Just a guess as good as any, but could be one of a thousand. Sometimes this happens to me when I have something keeping a key pressed down on my keyboard; like a stuck key, my phone is touching a key and I don't know, you get the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny thing this... my Synology NAS is sitting right behind my pc and I found out that it was responsible for the beep, not my pc. Now I just gotta find of what the beep means for the NAS.